# Update the "time" to automatically pick midnight and yesterday

Tags: sql

Unfortunately this is from work so I can not show a full description of what this is for. However, I want to write code so the date in the SQL function below would automatically set the "AND time >=" to yesterday at midnight and the other one to today at midnight.

Currently I have to update it manually.

[image]

Comment: What DBMS is this for?

Answer (score 0):

```
AND time >= TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1)
AND time < TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```